# if/else to test if a string is empty failing

Tags: strings, ifthenelse

Using the following

```
\def \ifempty#1{\def\temp{#1} \ifx\temp\empty }
\def \mymacro#1{ \ifempty{#1} empty \else not empty \fi }

\mymacro{something} % prints "not empty"
\mymacro{}          % prints "empty"
```

This all works until I introduce `\newcommand{\somename}{John}`:

```
\newcommand{\somename}{John}
\def \ifempty#1{\def\temp{#1} \ifx\temp\empty }
\def \mymacro#1{ \ifempty{#1} empty \else not empty \fi }

\mymacro{\somename{}} % prints "not empty"
```

This is correct. However when I change `\newcommand{\somename}{John}` to `\newcommand{\somename}{}` so that `\somename{}` is blank. `\mymacro` still thinks there is a string and prints "not empty" when in fact `\somename{}` is empty.

**Q:** How can I make `\mymacro{\someone{}}` work properly with `\newcommand{\somename}{}` and `\newcommand{\somename}{John}` ie if `\somename{}` holds a string `\mymacro` will print "not empty", and if `\somename{}` doesn't hold a string it should prints "empty"

Comment: In this specific case you can use `\xdef\temp` instead of `\def\temp` inside the definition of `\ifempty`. All macros will be fully expanded then when `\temp` is being defined. Note that this will only work if the matieral used as argument for `\mymacros` is fully expandable, e.g. `\mymacro{\def\name{}\name}` wouldn't work.

Comment: @siracusa thanks! It worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\ifx` compares the first level expansion of two macros, but also their status with respect to `\long`.

If you do `\def\temp{\somename{}}`, the replacement text is definitely not empty. Even if you do `\edef\temp{\somename{}}` (with empty replacement text for `\somename`) you'd get not empty, because the braces are still there.

Note that you need `\somename{}` in order to *print* the replacement text of `\somename` and respect spaces afterwards. The braces are not removed, but `{}` does nothing when typesetting is concerned.

A different approach:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ifempty}[1]{\ifnum\pdf@strcmp{#1}{}=\z@}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\mymacro}[1]{\ifempty{#1}empty\else not empty\fi}

\newcommand{\somename}{John}

\newcommand{\someothername}{}

\begin{document}

\mymacro{something}

\mymacro{}

\mymacro{\somename}

\mymacro{\someothername}

\end{document}
```

This will print

> not empty
>     empty
>     not empty
>     empty